# How to check if the identity function lies in a given set of functions to verify monoids?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, monoid

Let's say I have a set $A$ and $a$ $\in$ $A$. Suppose I have a set $N$ = {f $\in$ $A^A$| $f(a) = a$}. Now, I want to check if $N$ forms a monoid of functions on $A$. 
Now, by verifying associativity and closure, I have completed two tests. But, now I want to see if there exists an identity function in $N$.

Confusion: Based on the definition of the set, it seems to me like every function behaves as an identity function because no matter what $f$, $g$ I pick in $N$, they will map every element in A to the same element in A, which is the definition of identity function.

Is this right? Or is there something fundamentally wrong about the way I am thinking about monoids?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As it's written, $N$ is the set of functions which fix the element $a$ (which is a chosen element of $A$), not every element

Comment: hmm. that is an interesting catch. Thank you. So does it mean that there is no identity element in set $N$? I think I am just confused about how to conclude whether an id. function exists in $N$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have chosen *one* point $a\in A$. Your set of functions (in English) is the set of functions $f:A\to A$ which  fix the point $a$. Among these  functions is $\operatorname{Id}_A$ which is defined by $\operatorname{Id}_A(x)=x$ for all $x\in A$ because $\operatorname{Id}_A(a)=a$.